# Getting around a Typing errorr

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code which works fine in python:

```
Number = (int, float)
def number_squared(n: Number) -> Number:
    return n*n

number_squared(4)
# 16
number_squared(4.5)
# 20.25
```

Unfortunately, the `Typing` via mypy complains with the following:

> Variable "file.Number" is not valid as a type 
> Unsupported left operand type for * (Number?)

What is the proper way to do this with Typing? Or do I have to do all this boilerplate for this (for one function/type it's ok, but it adds up pretty quickly if there are a lot of them...):

```
Number = (int, float)
Number_Type = Union[int,float]
def number_squared(n: Number_Type) -> Number_Type: # pylint: disable=missing-function-docstring
    return n*n
```

One answerer (post since deleted) mentioned using `Union` directly in the annotation. The reason I've defined `Number` is so I can do things like `isinstance(x, Number)` and some other things...so I was hoping I could use that '`Number`' for typing as well without too many hurdles to jump over.

Comment: do `from numbers import Number`

Comment: @Samwise, ok, and for everything else?

Comment: In all other cases, do a thing.  (You'd need to give a specific example for me to say what specific thing you should do.  Numbers are a somewhat unique case.)

Comment: @samwise -- how about `Atom = (str, Number)` ?

Comment: What would you use such a type for?  (I assume you mean the type `Union[str, Number]` rather than `Tuple[str, Number]`...?)

Comment: @Samwise type detection in an interpreter. Yes it would be "this item is either a string or a number".

Comment: That's not how that works.  You might want to read up on the `ast` module, which is kind of a whole other thing from static typechecking.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#module-ast

Comment: That is to say, if you're writing a Python interpreter in Python, the tokens in the code that your interpreter is parsing are probably not going to have the same types as they do in the code of your interpreter itself.

Comment: Can someone please direct me to where I can learn about this form of passing parameters in a function "def number_squared(n: Number) -> Number:"